# How to convert decimal codepoint to UTF-16 Hex (java Syntax)?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, emoji

I have keycode = 57430

```
<Key android:codes="57430" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e056" />
```

How to convert decimal into UTF-16 Hex `0xE056`

[link](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/2/people/smiling-face-with-smiling-eyes)

Share your code

Comment: Does `String.format("%x", 57430);` satisfy your requirements?

Comment: No i want to convert 57430 into 0xE056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "into UTF-16 Hex `0xE056`", it's unclear whether you mean the string `0xE056` or the `char` character with that value.

To convert a string `57430` to an integer:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("57430");
```

To convert to hex string:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(value); // e056

String hex = Integer.toHexString(value).toUpperCase(); // E056

String hex = String.format("0x%04x", value); // 0xe056

String hex = String.format("0x%04X", value); // 0xE056
```

To convert to `char`:

```
char ch = (char)value; // Only for 0-65535

char[] ch = Character.toChars(value); // For any codepoint
```

To convert to `String`:

```
String symbol = new String(Character.toChars(value)); // For any codepoint
```

Comment: here problem please check this :int value = Integer.parseInt("" + primaryCode);

   String hex = String.format("0x%04x", value); // 0xe056
   String text = Character.toChars(codePoint)
   mComposing.append(hex);
   commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());